# Register a thumbnail handler for a folder, rather than a specific file type

Tags: windows, winapi, thumbnails, shell-extensions, callback-file-system

I need to write a thumbnail handler for all the files under a given folder. This folder is a mounting point for a virtual file system (using [Callback File System](https://www.eldos.com/cbfs/)), and the files are actually not present physically on the local machine (they're stored in the cloud), so if I let the default thumbnail handler do its work, it will try to download the whole files from the server... which is obviously not what I want.

But now I just realized that a thumbnail handler must be registered *per file type*:

> Registration of a thumbnail handler is based on standard file associations.

(from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144118.aspx))

I don't want to register it per file type, because I don't want to change the behavior for files that are not in my virtual folder. Is there a way for my handler to be called for all the files in my virtual folder, and only them?

Comment: Is file extension list fixed? Or your folder contains files with different extensions and you don`t know all of them?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov, no, the list isn't fixed. Files in the virtual folder can have any extension.

Comment: Shell namespace extension is the right solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways for you to go.

The simple way: Register your own thumbnail handler and let it work on all files. When you don't support `IInitializeWithStream` but only `IInitializeWithItem` or `IInitializeWithFile` you can check if the item/file is in your virtual file system. If so you can return a thumbnail and otherwise return an error.

The problem with this approach is that only one thumbnail provider can be registered per file type.

The hard way: You can write a shell namespace extension. These can be used to display virtual folders, which can be customized in many ways. This is another way to do what you already did using cbfs, but it is restricted to Explorer only. It would add another way to display your virtual folders.

The shell namespace extension will only work for it's own virtual folder. If you mapped your virtual folders to a drive letter and the user opens that drive in Explorer (and not the shell namespace extension's virtual folder), the user would see regular Explorer view of the files, not your shell namespace extension.

Also: Documentation for shell namespace extensions is a pain, there is not much available. I wrote my own shell namespace extension and every time my objects where queried for an IID I traced that and learned a bit more. I saw that my extension is queried for `IID_IThumbnailHandlerFactory`, I also saw IIDs like `IID_IExtractIconA` or `IID_IContextMenu`, but I did not see `IID_IThumbnailProvider`, nor did I see `IID_IExtractImage`. This suggests that you cannot have your own `IThumbnailProvider` directly attached to the objects you create for the virtual folder, but it could also be that I just missed to set some flag somewhere else so that Explorer does not even try to query me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The simple solution seems simple enough, but if I do that, thumbnails will be broken everywhere outside my virtual folder, won't they? Unless there is a way for my handler to call the default handler...

Comment: Explorer requests IExtractImage instead of IThumbnailProvider. And then it requests IThumbnailProvider from IExtractImage instance.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov, are you sure about that? From what I understand, IExtractImage is the old interface for thumbnails; since Vista it uses IThumbnailProvider instead

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, Yes, I am absolutely sure. IExtractImage still alive.

Comment: I would never do the "simple" way thing if it's for massive deployment to the world (only for a restricted number of user or intranet scenario). It's too big a responsability to basically hook the whole explorer IMHO. Namespace extensions is much cleaner (never said 'easy' though...).

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Sorry, I did not see that there is only one thumbnail provider per file type, I updated my answer.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov I did not see IExtractImage being queried in my namespace extension. But maybe I missed something.

Comment: @WernerHenze Part of logs from my NSE working on Win7: http://pastebin.ca/2874005

Comment: Namespace extension seems to solve the problem; thanks!